# XML over http using HttpURLConnection - getting error 401

Tags: java, curl, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send XML over http url using HttpURLConnection.

Following is the test curl command that I am using to test the service.

> curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "User-Agent: some/7.88/1" -X POST
>   --Basic -u "username:password" -d '< ?xml packet ...  >' http://ip:port/some/url

It is working fine, but when I try to send this with following Java code:

Java Code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://ip:port/some/url");   
String requestXMLPacket = "<?xml packet ... >"; 
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                  
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "some/7.88/1");
conn.setRequestProperty("basic -u", "username:password");

conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
```

I get an error:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
>   http://ip:port/some/url

Which means that I am not sending correct authorization.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding authentication header as follows

```
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

PS. It uses Java 8 Base64 encoder

Comment: For Java 7 use:
**org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String**